# Mysql query to select a distinct column and the count of a value in another column where column like distinct coumn?

Tags: mysql

My data table is as below:

```
ID WEEK   RESULT 
1   13     GOOD
2   13     BAD
3   13     GOOD
4   14     GOOD
5   14     BAD
6   15     BAD
```

I need  a sql query to create an array as below:

```
WWEK   GOOD_COUNT   BAD_COUNT
13            2             1 
14            1             1
15            0             1
```

Can anyone please help me to find an appropriate mysql query?

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: I tried the below query. But not working: SELECT WEEK, COUNT(SELECT * FROM table WHERE RESULT LIKE 'GOOD') AS GOOD_COUNT, COUNT(SELECT * FROM table WHERE RESULT LIKE 'BAD') AS BAD_COUNT FROM table;

Comment: @SaleejKuruniyan That is not the query that is in the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an aggregate function with a `CASE` expression to convert the rows into columns:

```
select week,
  sum(case when result = 'good' then 1 else 0 end) GoodResult,
  sum(case when result = 'bad' then 1 else 0 end) BadResult
from yt
group by week;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3fe82f/3)

Comment: WEEK   GOOD_COUNT   BAD_COUNT  TOTAL
13            2             1    3
14            1             1    2
15            0             1    1 ............What if I need an array like this as output?

Comment: @SaleejKuruniyan If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button.